# How to use Sox Library 'pad' command in mac os application to add silence to begining and end of audio file?

Tags: objective-c, macos, audio, sox, libsox

I am trying to add silence to begining and end of an audio wav file in a mac OS application(objective c). For that i am using sox library. i use prebuilt compiled framework from this [repo](https://github.com/KelvinJin/libsox-iOS). Dragged and dropped the libsox.a and sox.h files.

I am trying to use the 'pad' command. documentation of sox can be found [here](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html)

**Problem** is that the pad command does not produce expected results when used in code. However, pad command works perfectly fine on terminal.

**Lets take an example**

*Input file is like this*

[image: input file]

When i used pad command on terminal, it correctly adds silence to end and begining of file so i wrote on terminal

> sox in.wav out.wav pad 0.5 0.5

added 0.5 seconds silence at start and end and my file. so output looked like this(perfect)

*correct output from terminal*

[image: correct output]

But when i use it in code, the output is wrong

*unexpected output when used pad command from code*

[image: unexpected output]

As you can see in the above image. silence is added at the start, but not added at end correctly, the file is being **cut off from the end**. audio is moved from the start, but length of file is not increased as expected.

I have been trying to make this work for several days but failed to do so. i saw other Questions and googled it but could not find a solution.

> **Code that i am using** : https://www.codepile.net/pile/nL6xzjQ8

PS

1. File trimming(removing silence) works perfectly with sox with command "silence"
2. I am using [audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) tool for viewing the output audio files

What i searched and found.

[add silence to end of mp3](https://superuser.com/questions/536547/add-silence-to-the-end-of-an-mp3)

[How to removed start and end silence from audio file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273131/how-to-use-soxlib-for-ios-to-remove-start-and-end-silence)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks